# Instantly load Activity background

Tags: android

I've just started writing some simple android app. I would like to have full screen background  on my main activity. I've accomplished that by using :

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"`

and setting specific background in my layout file. It works, but not perfectly :| When I'm launching my app I see blank, black theme without any background for about 0.5 s and then my background loads. I've seen some commercial apps, which has their background load without any delay. Could anyone give me some hints how to get that done ?

Comment: Your image might be too big. What's the size?

Comment: It's only 93.5 KB. I think that's not the case.

Comment: File size means nothing.  What is the resolution and colour depth?  I can create a 93.5KB file which takes more than 1MB when loaded.

Comment: yes tell us the resolution of the image?

Comment: I've just checked the image properties in gimp. It says that my background is 480x800px, 96x96 ppi, RGB color. There is another parameter 'Size in memory:3.9MB', what's that and how is that realated to the size of file ?

Comment: The file you are using is a PNG right? so that is an image compression format. When used the image is decompressed into a Bitmap which takes a lot more memory. that is the size in memory and that will be causing memory issues when using a lot of images despite the fact that the ones you copied in the project are just up to 100kb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just how things work i am afraid. Using large images will cause larger loading times (time needed to decompress the image into a Bitmap and draw it on screen).

There are certainly options for you to optimize this. One obvious one is to use smaller images. You will have to weight in the pros/cons of doing that, if the reduced size of the image fits your needs or it looks pixelated.

Another thing that you could try is using Tiled bitmaps, meaning you have a small image which you can repeat vertically or horizontally if that is possible in your app.

You can even go to the extent of loading a reduced quality image at start, then start a background task to load the bitmap after onCreate and then replace the initial image with the better quality one after its done. (i wouldn't recommend this approach)

Answer (score 0):

*Reason of this problem is that activity takes some time to render. Window backgroud will set it before that*

This is the same problem i am facing. 
I resolved it by making custom theme .

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_pattern_bg</item>

</style>
```

Then use

```
android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
```

This will resolve your problem.